# Flash Collision

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs3

hello can you please help on the tut that im doing...
this is the tut site http://as3gametuts.com/2012/06/20/platformer-12/comment-page-1/#comment-800

and well i do not know whats the problem with the code that the bullet isnt colliding with the enemy.. this is the  code for it..

```
 function fireBullet():void {
    var playerDirection:String;
       if(player.scaleX < 0){
        playerDirection = "left";
    } else if(player.scaleX > 0){
        playerDirection = "right";
    }
    var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(player.x - scrollX, player.y - scrollY, playerDirection, xSpeed);
    back.addChild(bullet);
    bulletList.push(bullet);
    bullet.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED, bulletRemoved);

}
var bulletList:Array = new Array();
function bulletRemoved(e:Event):void {
e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED, bulletRemoved); //this just removes the eventListener so we don't get an error
bulletList.splice(bulletList.indexOf(e.currentTarget), 1); //this removes 1 object from the bulletList, at the index of whatever object caused this function to activate
}
//bullet

//enemies
var enemyList:Array = new Array();
function addEnemy(xLocation:int, yLocation:int):void{
var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy(xLocation, yLocation);
back.addChild(enemy);
enemy.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED, enemyRemoved);
enemyList.push(enemy);
}
function addEnemy1(xLocation:int, yLocation:int):void{
var enemy1:Enemy1 = new Enemy1(xLocation, yLocation);
back.addChild(enemy1); 
enemy1.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED, enemyRemoved);
enemyList.push(enemy1);
}
function enemyRemoved(e:Event):void{
e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED, enemyRemoved); //this just removes the eventListener so we don't get an error
enemyList.splice(enemyList.indexOf(e.currentTarget), 1); //this removes 1 object from the enemyList, at the index of whatever object caused this function to activate
}

addEnemiesToLevel1();

function addEnemiesToLevel1():void{
addEnemy(272.8, 19.8);
addEnemy(959, 278.8);
addEnemy1(374.1, 305.1);
addEnemy1(966, 29);
}
```

This is the Main Loop

```
//main loop 
function loop(e:Event):void{


if(back.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + leftBumpPoint.x, player.y + leftBumpPoint.y, true)){
    trace("leftBumping");
    leftBumping = true;
} else {
    leftBumping = false;
}

if(back.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + rightBumpPoint.x, player.y + rightBumpPoint.y, true)){
    trace("rightBumping");
    rightBumping = true;
} else {
    rightBumping = false;
}
/* 
if(back.hitTestPoint(player.x + upBumpPoint.x, player.y + upBumpPoint.y, true)){
    trace("upBumping");
    upBumping = true;
} else {
    upBumping = false;
}
//added upbump

if(back.hitTestPoint(player.x + upBumpPoint1.x, player.y + upBumpPoint1.y, true)){
    trace("upBumping");
    upBumping = true;
} else {
    upBumping = false;
}
if(back.hitTestPoint(player.x + upBumpPoint2.x, player.y + upBumpPoint2.y, true)){
    trace("upBumping");
    upBumping = true;
} else {
    upBumping = false;
}
*/
if(back.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + downBumpPoint.x, player.y + downBumpPoint.y, true)){
    trace("downBumping");
    downBumping = true;
} else {
    downBumping = false;
}
 if(back.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + downBumpPoint1.x, player.y + downBumpPoint1.y, true)){
    trace("downBumping");
    downBumping = true;
} else {
    downBumping = false;
}

    if(leftPressed){
        xSpeed -= speedConstant;
         player.scaleX = -1

    } else if(rightPressed){
        xSpeed += speedConstant;
         player.scaleX = 1
    }

    /*if(upPressed){
        ySpeed -= speedConstant;

    } else if(downPressed){
        ySpeed += speedConstant;

    }*/
 if(leftBumping){
    if(xSpeed < 0){
        xSpeed *= -0.5;
    }
}

if(rightBumping){
    if(xSpeed > 0){
        xSpeed *= -0.5;
    }
}
/*up bump 
if(upBumping){
    if(ySpeed < 0){
        ySpeed *= -0.3;
    }
}
 */
if(downBumping){ //if we are touching the floor
     if(ySpeed > 0){
          ySpeed = 0;
     }
     if(upPressed){ //and if the up arrow is pressed
          ySpeed = jumpConstant; //set the y speed to the jump constant
     }
} else {
     ySpeed += gravityConstant;
}
//max speed
if(xSpeed > maxSpeedConstant){ //moving right
     xSpeed = maxSpeedConstant;
} else if(xSpeed < (maxSpeedConstant * -1)){ //moving left
     xSpeed = (maxSpeedConstant * -1);
}
//min sped
if(Math.abs(xSpeed) < 0.5){
     xSpeed = 0;
}

//keycollection
if(keyCollected == false){ // if we still haven't collected the key
    if(player.hitTestObject(back.other.doorKey)){ // and if the player collides with the key
        back.other.doorKey.visible = false; // hide the key from view
        keyCollected = true; // set our Boolean to true
         //key score
          score += 40;
        }
         updateScore(score);
}
if(doorOpen == false){ // if the door hasn't been opened yet
     if(keyCollected == true){ // and if the player has already collected the key  
          if(player.hitTestObject(back.other.lockedDoor)){ // check if the door and the player are touching
               // if all of these conditions are met...
               back.other.lockedDoor.gotoAndStop(2); // ...switch the door's image to its 2nd frame
               doorOpen = true; // ...set the variable to true
          }
     }

}

    xSpeed *= friction;
    ySpeed *= friction;

    scrollX -= xSpeed;
    scrollY -= ySpeed;

    back.x = scrollX;
    back.y = scrollY;

    mount.x=scrollX * 0.6;
    mount.y=scrollY * 0.6;

    sky.x = scrollX * 0.4;
    sky.y = scrollY * 0.4;

 //movement logic

if(player.currentLabel != animationState){
     player.gotoAndStop(animationState);
}

if( ( leftPressed || rightPressed || xSpeed > speedConstant || xSpeed < speedConstant *-1 ) && downBumping){
     animationState = "running";
}
if( ( leftPressed || rightPressed || xSpeed > speedConstant || xSpeed < speedConstant *-1 ) && downBumping){
     animationState = "running";
} else if(downBumping){
     animationState = "idle";

} else {
     animationState = "jumping";
}
if (enemyList.length > 0) // if there are any enemies left in the enemyList{
for (var i:int = 0; i < enemyList.length; i++) // for each enemy in the enemyList
{
    if (bulletList.length > 0) // if there are any bullets alive
    {
        for (var j:int = 0; j < bulletList.length; j++) // for each bullet in the bulletList
        {
            if ( enemyList[i].hitTestObject(bulletList[j]) )
            {
                trace("Bullet and Enemy are colliding");
                enemyList[i].removeSelf();
                bulletList[j].removeSelf();
            }

            // enemyList[i] will give you the current enemy
            // bulletList[j] will give you the current bullet
            // this will check all combinations of bullets and enemies
            // and see if any are colliding
        }
    }
}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i can answer my own question.. -_-
putting`enemy.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED, enemyRemoved); on 
'function addEnemy(xLocation:int, yLocation:int):void{` isnt appropriate coz it will instanly turn the array to 0; so the object will be impossible to collide with.. i transferred the enemy removed into the mainloop.. and it worked just fine..